# Were there specific locusts in reserve for the 8th plague?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, commentaries, bugs, plagues-makkos, bo

Hashem's instructions to Moshe to bring the locusts reads as follows:

> וַיֹּאמֶר יְהֹוָה אֶל משֶׁה נְטֵה יָדְךָ עַל אֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם בָּאַרְבֶּה וכו
>
> And Hashem said to Moses, "stretch out your hand over the land of Egypt for **the** locusts..."

The vowel under the ב of בארבה is a qamatz, which is in place of the definitive article ה.  (See [here](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%22%D7%90_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%94) for more about that.)  This indicates that there were some specific locusts that were being referred to by this verse (i.e. send *the* locusts as opposed to send locusts).

I think Rashi is addressing his point with his comment to this word,

> בארבה: בשביל מכת הארבה
>
> For the locusts: for the plague of locusts

thus making the definitive article referring to the plague, as opposed to the locusts.

However, I am wondering if there is any other approach to this in the commentaries.  Does anyone explain that there were some specific, otherwise known, locusts that were involved in this plague?

Comment: Wasn't sure about the parshanut tag, but I ran out of room.  If someone thinks it's a better fit than any of the above, feel free to switch it in.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40591/4794

Answer (score 1):

See Rashi's explanation in [Shemot 10:14](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=132) regarding the phrase "... there was never Arbeh like it and afterwards there will not be...". Rashi explains that there are different species of locusts one of which is called *arbeh*. He explains that this plague of locusts in Egypt was only of that species called *arbeh*. So, I'm assuming that the use of the definite article in your verse parallels this idea, that Moshe should cause **the** arbeh, meaning to exclude the other species of locusts.

English has similar usage of the definitive article. Example:
Mom says to child, "You have so many marbles - blue, red, green and yellow. Which do you want to play with?"
Child says, "I'll play with **the** blue ones"

Comment: An interesting suggestion, +1.  Note that when Moshe tells Pharaoh, he refers to indefinite locusts (10:4) - with your explanation, Moshe could just as well have told Pharaoh about **the** arbeh (although I realize it wouldn't be _necessary_, but thought I would point it out).

Comment: @YeZ - It's possible that G-d didn't tell Moshe the exact nature of the plague, i.e., being just 1 species. Also, keep in mind that we're projecting an explanation of future events onto a "current" event. I.e. - Rashi is trying to resolve a conflict between the Torah's "prediction" and what eventually occurred.